# Kubernetes and starting environments in the morning on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, constraints

We turn off environments over night and then start them again in the morning. We do this by turning our ASGs to 0 nodes over night. On turning them back on, we obviously see a large hit on the CPU across all boxes, which in turn ends up timing out the readiness & liveness probles and then the pods get killed.

How can I configure the deployments, pods, etc. such that Kubernetes throttles the number of ongoing deployments. If I can say max x deployments and x is the number of nodes, then despite all pods being scheduled they won't steal the CPU.

Previously, we've written scripts to turn all replicaCounts to 0 and then restoring to the original value - but that seems a bit onerous and no doubt K8s has a feature we can leverage.

Cheers

- Reading the docs
- Scaling more nodes first to scale down later